# Will Allah forgive me if i repent

Tags: sin, shirk, forgiveness, tawba, akhirah

I want to know that is a person asks for forgiveness from All sins major or minor even from shirk if he repents then can he be forgiven if the person commits even the bigest sin of all but seeks forgiveness before death? And to be forgiven after death as well?

Comment: Please stop asking the same questions over and over.

Comment: https://youtu.be/6eeqrEplfao -watch this

Answer (score 0):

"Surely, Allah forgives all sins. He is the Opt-forgiving, the Most Merciful."
Yes, if you repent before death, it will be forgiven. Make sure to repent and make a vow to never commit that particular sin again but as soon as you die, it's too late, NOTHING will be accepted no matter what (Just like how Phir'awn was drowned by Allah {SWT} by a tidal wave and his repentance was not accepted).